# Cannot echo headTitle in layout view

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

I got my headTitle up running, except i cannot echo it in my layout file as i need it for page header.

This is how i done it:

Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initDefaultHelpers() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->headTitle('Awesome Website');
    $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
```

My Controller:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->getView()->headTitle('IndexPage');        
}
```

When i open index i get: Awesome Website - IndexPage, which is perfect.

But in my master.phtml where i use:

```
<?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
```

Gives absolutely nothing. At this point i only want the title "IndexPage" and not the entire title, so this also has to be considered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this work: tested by me locally after creating a new project with zend tool!**

//application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Foo"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

; layout stuff
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

; view stuff
resources.view[] = ""

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

//into Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initDefaultHelpers() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->headTitle('Foo');
    $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' :: ');
    $view->doctype("XHTML1_STRICT");
}
```

//into layout.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="it" xml:lang="it">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <?=$this->headTitle()?>

</head>
<body>
    <?=$this->pageTitle?>
    <?=$this->layout()->content?>

</body>
</html>
```

//into view

```
<? $this->pageTitle("Bar"); ?>
```

//create view/helper/PageTitle.php

```
<?
class Zend_View_Helper_PageTitle extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function pageTitle($title)
    {
        $this->view->headTitle($title);
        $this->view->pageTitle = '<h1>' . $title . '</h1>';
    }
}
```

After that the name of your page will be: **Foo :: Bar**

Comment: I get following error from my view: 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function headTitle() on a non-object in /.../index.phtml`